# Getting rid of 'less: XHR: Getting 'http://foo.less' message on console

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, less

Whenever I reload the page of my angular app, I get tens of lines of 'less: XHR: Getting 'http:myless library'' on the console. I looked for ways I could stop this behavior, but no luck so far. Can any one explain why this is happening and what could be done to stop it?

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but in case anyone is looking...

Less can have different log levels. The levels are

```
2 - Information and errors
1 - Errors
0 - Nothing
```

The default is 2.

To change it to 0 add a script tag similar to below in your html before the less.js or less.min.js file is loaded.

```
<script>
    less = {
      logLevel: 0,
    };
</script>
```

This will stop the "less: XHR: Getting ..." messages in the console.